# Nutch : Filter URLs at Indexing time

Tags: url, indexing, solr, nutch

I am crawling sites using Nutch and integrating it with Solr. 
I am crawling all the URLs on the site, but want to index only a few of them.

Adding URL pattern in **regex_urlfilter.txt** would filter the URLs from *crawling*. But, that, however, isn't what I am looking for. I want to crawl all the sites, but index only a few.

Is there something like regex-urlfilter.txt at index time rather than at crawl time?

Comment: Its simplest solution is, you should crawl only those websites that you want to index. Those websites that you do not want to index, crawl them seperately

Answer (score 0):

When doing step by step.

Don't supply filter until the dedup step.Once your urls have been updated to crawlDb and you ready for indexing,supply the filter to regex-urlfilter.txt.

Do as **bin/nutch index .... -filter**

Comment: Yes, I tried the bin/nutch index .. -filter option.  But will only regex-urlfilter.txt be used? Can we not specify another file for that?

Comment: The `-filter` option will instantiate all the URL filters defined in your configuration file, so if you have different files with different URL filters enabled you could have 2 filtering policies (at crawl and at index time).